# SWIG: function returning an object from another module

Tags: c++, swig, gdal

I would like to know if it is possible to mix object from two modules using SWIG, e.g. is it possible for a function of the module A to return an object of a module B?

My use case for that is the following:

**class_a.hpp:**

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    const OGRPolygon& get_geom() const;
    void set_geom(OGRPolygon* geom);
protected:
    OGRPolygon* _footprint;
};
```

**class_a.cpp:**

```
const OGRPolygon& ForCity::SPreC_cpp::ClassA::get_geom() const
{
    return *(this->_footprint);
}

void ForCity::SPreC_cpp::ClassA::set_geom(OGRPolygon* geom)
{
    this->_footprint = geom;
}
```

**test.i:**

```
%module test
%include "class_A.hpp"
```

Then in Python, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
A = test.ClassA()
G = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
# filling the geometry...
A.set_geom(G) # set the geometry of A
A.get_geom().GetArea() # use the geometry of A as a usual OGR geometry
```

Is it possible and how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by including `%import ClassB` directive in your `.i` file. This directive reads type information but does not generate bindings.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be the way to do it but I did not manage to make it work. When I import `gdal.i` I get many errors when the file `testPYTHON_wrap.cxx` is built. I can resolve most of them by including `python_exceptions.i` but then I still have the error: `‘CPLErrorHandler’ does not name a type`. I tried to import or include some other files but it does not work :(

Comment: Did you include both headers to `testPYTHON_wrap.cxx`? You can do it from the `test.i` by writing `%inline { #include "your_header.h" %}`.

Comment: Yes I did. But GDAL is a quite big library the depends on other libraries like GEOS so I guess it is a quite big deal to wrap it. For now I found a stupid solution: I copy my geometries from C++ to python using wkb :) For what I want to do it is enought but would be nice to have a real wrapping.